# Theme not affecting tabs

Tags: java, android, android-theme

I have created a theme for my application using this action bar style generator.

http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

I have set the tab colors to orange, but it's not affecting the tabs in my layout.

My layout looks the following.

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabFrameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Here are the other things I have in my style files and in the manifest file.

The Manifest file

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Silence"
```

styles_silence.xml

```
<style name="Theme.Silence" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Silence</item>
    ...
</style>
...
<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Silence" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_silence</item>
</style>
```

tab_indicator_ab_silence.xml (this is generated by the program I linked earlier)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_silence" />

    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_focused_silence" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused_silence" />

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <!--    Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_silence" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_silence" />

    <!--    Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_silence" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_silence" />
</selector>
```

I checked [this document](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomTabs), and it seems to me that everything is alright. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What could be wrong?

That tool generates the styles for the tabs present in the `ActionBar`, but you're using normal tabs(through the standard `TabWidget`) which have a different style associated with them. That style is represented in the theme by the `tabWidgetStyle` attribute which points to the style `Widget.(Holo).TabWidget` style.

Unfortunately through the `Widget.TabWidget` style of the theme you can't change the background(and neither the tab layout as the attribute which manages this is hidden) but you can do it manually by assigning a new layout as the tab indicator and placing your selector in there:

```
fragmentTabHost.addTab(fragmentTabHost.newTabSpec("tabText").setIndicator(buildTabLayout("tabText")), YourFragmentClass.class, null);
```

where `buildTabLayout()` is a method like this:

```
private View buildTabLayout(String tag) {
    View tab = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.new_tab_layout, null);      
    return tab;
}
```

The layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_silence" // or you could have a style attribute
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" android:text="simple"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works too, but is a little bit weird way. You mentioned the ActionBar way. Did you mean [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs)? If I didn't completely misunderstood, it works with API 10 with the support library. Am I correct?

Comment: @MikkoP I've spoken about the `ActionBar`, mentioning that the styles don't match. The `ActionBar` has a different implementation for the tabs view and controller and it **doesn't** use a `TabHost`(along with a `TabWidget`), so the styles will also be different. The link you posted is referring to the tabs of the `ActionBar`(which you could indeed implement for lower API versions but this doesn't matter as you're dealing with a `TabHost` in the **content view** part of the app).

Comment: What do you mean by "but this doesn't matter as you're dealing with a TabHost in the content view part of the app"? I was thinking if I replaced my TabWidget with this.

Comment: @MikkoP The link is not relevant to what you are asking, in the end those are still `ActionBar` tabs and not the `TabHost` you use. *I was thinking if I replaced my TabWidget with this* - this I can't answer I don't know you're app's structure.

Comment: I changed my current TabWidget implementation to use ActionBar with the support library instead. Now it's working out of the box. I have some problems with it though, but I'll post a new question about that. Thanks!

Comment: Posted the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642295/actionbar-tab-contents-overlapping

Comment: You are not assigning the tag to the textview in `buildTabLayout()`.

Answer (score 1):

Copy paste the following res/values-v14/styles.xml

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!--
    Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
    res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item><!-- your theme name -->
        <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@null</item>
    </style>

    <!-- style for the action bar backgrounds -->
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/tab_bar_bg</item> <!-- change your image -->
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBar.Text</item> <!-- to cusomize the font style on tab bar --.
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar.Text" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">#A3A3A3</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Change the default theme to your theme In AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <application
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       ----
       ----
    </application>
```