# ActionBar tab contents overlapping

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs, android-actionbar

I found a ton of these messages in StackOverflow. Like those many other people, I have the same problem with tab contents overlapping when switching tabs. None of the advises I found didn't work with my problem.

When my app launches, it correctly shows the contents of the first tab. When I click the other tab, the old contents stay on the screen and the other tab's content is added on the screen, too. When switching tabs second time, all the contents disappear. Switching tabs won't do anyhting anymore.

I followed Google's Developer document [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs).

My application has this `onCreate` method.. The class extends `ActionBarActivity` from the support libary `android.support.v7.app`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    Tab tab = actionBar.newTab().setText("TAB1").setTabListener(new TabListener<Tab1Class>(this, "tab1", Tab1Class.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = actionBar.newTab().setText("TAB2").setTabListener(new TabListener<Tab2Class>(this, "tab2", Tab2Class.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);
}
```

My `TabListener` class is copied from the page I linked:

```
public class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private Fragment mFragment;
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;

    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if(mFragment == null) {
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
            ft.attach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if(mFragment != null) {
            ft.detach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {} 
}
```

Both classes I use as the contents of the tabs extend Fragment from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. They inflate their layouts in `onCreateView` methods.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What's wrong?

After a quick look through the code for the `ActionBarActivity`, there seems to be a bug for the `ICS` and above part of the implementation of the `ActionBar`(the code should work for pre `ICS` devices) which also takes care of the tabs.

In the `ActionBarImplICS` class which represents the implementation for `ICS` devices it seems the `FragmentTransaction` passed to the `onTabUnselected()` callback is completely useless as it isn't committed anywhere after the listener's callback returns(the transaction is committed for the other two callbacks of the `TabListener`). So a committed fragment will never be detached from the layout on a tab selection and it will stay getting the overlapping content(due to the `FrameLayout` which holds both fragments).

I've written another implementation of the `TabListener` interface which does all of its job from only one of the callbacks which isn't affected by the above bug(`onTabSelected()`):

```
public class TabListenerImpl implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private List<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();
    private Context mContext;

    public TabListenerImpl(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // iterate over all of the tabs, match the tag we have and see if
        // we also have a fragment instance for it. If we don't, create one
        // and add it to the container, if we have an instance simply attach
        // it. Detach every other tag which doesn't match the tag.
        for (TabInfo t : mTabs) {
            if (tab.getTag() == t.tag) {
                if (t.pageFragment == null) {
                    t.pageFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mContext,
                            t.clazz.getName());
                    ft.add(android.R.id.content, t.pageFragment, t.tag);
                } else {
                    ft.attach(t.pageFragment);
                }
            } else {
                if (t.pageFragment != null && !t.pageFragment.isDetached()) {
                    ft.detach(t.pageFragment);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // faulty method
    }

    /**
     * Call this method BEFORE you call the actionBar.addTab() method!
     * 
     * @param tag
     *            a String representing the tag that was set on the tab to
     *            identify itself
     * @param clazz
     *            the class of the Fragment
     */
    public void addTab(String tag, Class<? extends Fragment> clazz) {
        TabInfo ti = new TabInfo();
        ti.clazz = clazz;
        ti.tag = tag;
        mTabs.add(ti);
    }

    // wrapper class
    private class TabInfo {
        Class<? extends Fragment> clazz;
        Fragment pageFragment;
        String tag;
    }

}
```

Which you could then use as:

```
TabListenerImpl listener = new TabListenerImpl(this);
Tab tab = actionBar.newTab().setText("TAB1").setTag("TAB1").setTabListener(listener);
listener.addTab("TAB1", Tab1Class.class);
actionBar.addTab(tab);

tab = actionBar.newTab().setText("TAB2").setTag("TAB2").setTabListener(listener);
listener.addTab("TAB2", Tab2Class.class);
actionBar.addTab(tab);
```

I would advise you to set a container as the content view(and also for the tab content) and not use the `android.R.id.content` container. Keep in mind that my implementation doesn't take care of configuration changes.

Comment: Awesome! I have faced a ton of problems because I want the application to work on API 10 devices. I hope people would ditch those old phones and get newer ones with Android 4. BTW, do you know why my application doesn't have a title when using these tabs? Or why my menu collapses into these dots even I have `android:showAsAction="always"`?

Comment: @MikkoP *do you know why my application doesn't have a title when using these tabs?* - this is happening only when you use the tabs? And you can always use the `actionBar.setTitle()` method. *Or why my menu collapses into these dots even I have android:showAsAction="always"?* - do you have menu items in the overflow menu(the popup which appears when clicking the 3 dots image)?

Comment: It only happens when I use these tabs. `actionBar.setTitle()` doesn't change anything, neither does `setTitle()` from the Activity. And yes, these menu items are showing in the overflow menu. I posted a new question again, so if someone answers it, there is a better possibility that some other could find it and get helped. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19660334/menu-collapsing-when-using-actionbar-tabs-for-navigation

Comment: A reference here, "Issue 58602: Support AppCompat - onTabUnselected does not call tx.commit() on ICS", https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58602