# Menu collapsing when using ActionBar tabs for navigation

Tags: java, android, menu, android-actionbar

I have used ActionBar from the support library to build my application a tabbed navigation bar. I have two tabs in my application. Both of these Fragments have menus and they have one menu item and I'd like to show it as an action in the action bar, but for some reason the overflow icon is shown instead of the icons assigned to these items. They are shown as text under the dropdown menu.

My XML looks the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/my_id"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new"
        android:title="New"/>
</menu>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: From your other questions I've seen that you used the compatibility package. Which `Activity` does your app's activity extends(`ActionBarActivity`, `FragmentActivity`)? If you use the `ActionBarActivity` check this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems (read the note at the bottom pf the paragraph)to see how to declare that action attribute.

Comment: Great as always! I changed the namespace for that attribute, and now it works. Please post this as an answer :)

Comment: Did you solved the title part?

Comment: See the `setDisplayShowTitleEnabled()` method of the `ActionBar` and set it to `true`, in the tutorial is set to `false`.

Comment: Haha, great, it seems I'm blind! It couldn't be any more clearer. "setDisplayShowTitleEnabled" lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using the activities from the compatibility package, make sure that you use the proper namespaces when building the menu item([link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems)). Here's a note from the guide to the menu item implementation:

**Using XML attributes from the support library**

*Notice that the **showAsAction** attribute above uses a custom namespace defined in the  tag. This is necessary when using any XML attributes defined by the support library, because these attributes do not exist in the Android framework on older devices. So you must use your own namespace as a prefix for all attributes defined by the support library.*