# Android - Fragment from support library doesn't compatible well with 4.3 platform

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I encounter a weird problem while using the support library.

---

I want to make a dynamic navigation tabs with fragments switching on the 2.3.3 platform, just like what `API Demo` did .

[image]

---

everything goes fine on 2.3.3 platform, but when I took a look at the same activity on the 4.3 platform, I found that something quite weird.

the `SupportFragmentManagement` cannot detach the fragment, seems like the tab selecting callback didn't execute correctly;

following pictures show how my demo go
[image]

and here's my code:

```
package net.zengweizhi.android.gettingstarted.lesson05.test;
import net.zengweizhi.android.gettingstarted.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

**// using the api from support library**

> ```
> import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
> import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
> import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
> import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab;
> import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
> import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
> ```

```
public class NavigationTabsWithFragmentsV9 extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_navigation_tabs, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.actionButton_addTab:
            addTab();
            break;
        case R.id.actionButton_removeTab:
            removeTab();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private int mTabSeq = 0;

    private void addTab(){
        getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        mTabSeq++;

        Tab tab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
        tab.setText("TAB " + mTabSeq);
        tab.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(this));
        getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab);
    }

    private void removeTab(){
        Tab tab = getSupportActionBar().getSelectedTab();
        getSupportActionBar().removeTab(tab);

        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tab.getText().toString());
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
        if( getSupportActionBar().getTabCount() == 0 ){
            getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        }
    }

    private static final class MyTabListener  implements TabListener {
        private NavigationTabsWithFragmentsV9 mActivity;
        public MyTabListener(NavigationTabsWithFragmentsV9 activity /*,Fragment fragment*/){
            mActivity = activity;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // Do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            Object obj = tab.getTag();
            if( null == obj ){
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString(SimpleFragment.EXTRA_OUTPUT_MESSAGE, tab.getText().toString());
                Fragment fragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, SimpleFragment.class.getName(), args);
                ft.add(android.R.id.content, fragment, tab.getText().toString());

                tab.setTag(obj = fragment);
            }

            ft.attach((Fragment)obj);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            if( null != mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tab.getText().toString()) ){
                ft.detach((Fragment)tab.getTag());
            }
        }

    }

    public static final class SimpleFragment extends Fragment {
        public static final String EXTRA_OUTPUT_MESSAGE = "output_message";

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_simple, container, false);

            String outputMesasge = null;
            if( null != getArguments() ){
                outputMesasge = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_OUTPUT_MESSAGE);
            }
            if( null == outputMesasge || 0 == outputMesasge.trim().length() ){
                outputMesasge = getString(R.string.demo_text);
            }
            TextView textView = (TextView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.textView_simpleFragmentOutput);
            textView.setText(outputMesasge);

            return fragmentView;
        }
    }
}
```

---

But when I change all the`support api` to the `regular api(default platform api)`, everything goes fine on 4.3 platform(but this one doesn't compatible with 2.3.3 platform);

[image]

here's the code(nothing difference except the ActionBar and Fragment API)

```
package net.zengweizhi.android.gettingstarted.lesson05.test;

import net.zengweizhi.android.gettingstarted.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

> **// use the api from default platform(only in v11 and later)**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

**@SuppressLint("NewApi")**

```
public class NavigationTabsWithFragmentsV14 extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_navigation_tabs, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private int mTabSeq = 0;

    private void addTab(){
        getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        mTabSeq++;

        Tab tab = getActionBar().newTab();
        tab.setText("TAB " + mTabSeq);
        tab.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(this));
        getActionBar().addTab(tab);
    }

    private void removeTab(){
        Tab tab = getActionBar().getSelectedTab();
        getActionBar().removeTab(tab);

        Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tab.getText().toString());
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
        if( getActionBar().getTabCount() == 0 ){
            getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.actionButton_addTab:
            addTab();
            break;
        case R.id.actionButton_removeTab:
            removeTab();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private static final class MyTabListener  implements TabListener {
        private NavigationTabsWithFragmentsV14 mActivity;
        public MyTabListener(NavigationTabsWithFragmentsV14 activity /*,Fragment fragment*/){
            mActivity = activity;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // Do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            Object obj = tab.getTag();
            if( null == obj ){ // initialize fragment to tab
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString(SimpleFragment.EXTRA_OUTPUT_MESSAGE, tab.getText().toString());
                Fragment fragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, SimpleFragment.class.getName(), args);
                ft.add(android.R.id.content, fragment, tab.getText().toString());

                tab.setTag(obj = fragment);
            }
            ft.attach((Fragment)obj);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            if( null != mActivity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tab.getText().toString()) ){
                ft.detach((Fragment)tab.getTag());
            }
        }
    }

    public static final class SimpleFragment extends Fragment {
        public static final String EXTRA_OUTPUT_MESSAGE = "output_message";

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_simple, container, false);

            String outputMesasge = null;
            if( null != getArguments() ){
                outputMesasge = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_OUTPUT_MESSAGE);
            }
            if( null == outputMesasge || 0 == outputMesasge.trim().length() ){
                outputMesasge = getString(R.string.demo_text);
            }
            TextView textView = (TextView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.textView_simpleFragmentOutput);
            textView.setText(outputMesasge);

            return fragmentView;
        }
    }
}
```

---

I can make a compatible version by using (values-v14/classes.xml) and following code

```
try {
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(getString(R.string.class_navigationTabsAndFragmentsActivity));
    startActivity(clazz);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    showTextByToast(ex.getMessage());
}
```

but I still want to know what's going on in the `support library` version, can anyone help me to figure out this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642295/actionbar-tab-contents-overlapping/19644639#19644639

Comment: Thanks a lot @Luksprog; How strange, didn't android team realize this promblem, or they just changed that on other purpose? Should I still use the support library; left a bug like that just likes left a time boom;

Comment: I don't know if someone posted a bug report. I would still use the library and be on the watch for a update to the compatibility package(which come more often) which could solve it.

Comment: @Luksprog you're right, and your solution is good; but I still want to fix this up in the support v7 project, and I found the source code of [support library](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/), I will take a look at the code, and give my solution on this topic later :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google releases Nexus 5 and a new support library (v19), this version fixed this bug
[image]